# Multiple app were running in background , how to close them properly, autodesk forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

It is a forge app question. The app is created in visual studio and forge app. I was debugging.  I am working on a forge application where I am using Data management, design automation and model derivatives. Design automation app were closing properly. After integrating Model Derivative I was passing rfa file by mistake and app was running endlessly.. The model is very small, but initially I did some mistake while passing the model to model derivative. I was passing rfa file, later realise model derivatives do not read rfa file. In the mean time I tried so many times. After passing a rvt file to model derivative, it was very fast and was running perfect. I had deleted those hanged apps. When they were running endlessly and did not show the model in the viewer, I closed the app and rerun the app or deleted the app and created a new one and rerun. Then when I saw data usage,it shows multiple apps were consuming cloud credit.Is it possible, multiple app were running simultaneously and the jobs which I had deleted did not close properly? The test model was really small.
I had stopped the app abruptly and debug again. I can guess, multiply apps were running one upon another. It is my guess. I can be wrong.

Please let me know few known reasons, for app running in background and how to properly end a job in forge cloud platform. I simply stopped debugging in visual studio and deleted the app in forge and created a new one.

In the usage graph, it is showing overlapping colors and usage of several app. My new model for design automation is big, my worry is I will lost all of my cloud credit if I do not close the jobs properly.
How to stop a project running in forge cloud. I am sure I could not stop app running in cloud properly before creating a new forge app and debug. All of them were running. I can be wrong, because I am new to forge cloud.

I described above, what can go wrong. Please let me know what could go wrong. Model was really small.

May be Ngrok was not closed properly. No idea.
I thought I closed each job, before starting a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model Derivative API doesn't support RFA format currently. With my experience, it will the following message while submitting a translation job on the RFA file with [POST Jobs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/). Therefore, I'm not sure why you're saying the job or the app keeps running endlessly. Could you share more details on that??

```
{
    "diagnostic": "Failed to trigger translation for this file."
}
```

Besides, I'm confused with your statement here. What kind of app was deleted? The Forge app inside your [myapp page](https://forge.autodesk.com/myapps)? It's unclear to me.

> I had deleted those hanged apps. When they were running endlessly and
> did not show the model in the viewer, I closed the app and rerun the
> app or deleted the app and created a new one and rerun.

To cancel or delete translation jobs, you can call [DELETE manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-DELETE/). According to our engineering team, each translation job has designed expire time (e.g. 2 hours). If your translation job cannot be completed within the period, then the job will be canceled immediately by our service.

**Note.** To cancel a Desing Automation WorkItem, you can call [DELETE  workitems/:id](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/workitems-id-DELETE/) to stop the job.

Lastly, back to the cloud credits question, Model Derivative API is charging per translation job while calling [POST Jobs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/), not by the processing hour. Currently, only the Design Automation API is charging by the processing hour of your work item, see the pricing table here: https://forge.autodesk.com/pricing.

If you have further questions, you can drop me a line to forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com.

Cheers,

Comment: I have replied you in next answer, please read. I am new to this forum, not allowing me to reply longer than certain number of words